# Select posts by name and category per REST API

Tags: categories, ajax, search, rest-api

I have a site with a form, the form has 3 inputs. One takes a number, another a date, and another a select option. I made posts with categories from this select. How could I search on click of the submit button for exactly 1 post whose name is this number and it should be only from the category which is selected? Thank you!

Comment: Is the category even necessary? Post names are unique, I doubt REST API endpoints are necessary either, a simple form would do